# Correct output in if ..elif in shell scripting

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have the following sell code

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "hello"
echo "enter the salutation $abc"
read -r abc
if [ "$abc" = "1" ]
then
 echo "Hiiii"
elif [ "$abc" = "2" ]
then
echo "haaaaa"
fi
echo "enter name $xyz"
read -r xyz
if 
if [ "$xyz" = "1" ]
then
 echo "Chris"
elif [ "$xyz" = "2" ]
then
echo "Morris"
fi
echo "you had put salutation as" "$abc"
echo "you entered name as " "$xyz"
```

I need the final printing to be like

```
 you had put salutation as Hii
 you entered name as chris
```

what I get is

```
 you had put salutation as 1
 you entered name as 1
```

> Any help? Do I need to mention the final statement inside the if elif
>   statement?

Comment: What did you enter when you are prompted for `salutation` and `name` respectively?

Comment: @anthony I entered 1 for both

Comment: Your code in question is not complete. It throws syntax error: `test.sh: line 24: syntax error: unexpected end of file`. Won't produce the output you said you saw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use:

```
#!/bin/bash

PS3="Enter the salutation>"
select abc in Hiii Haaa; do
    [[ "$abc" ]] && break
done

PS3="Enter name>"
select xyz in Chris Morris; do
    [[ "$xyz" ]] && break
done

echo "you had put salutation as" "$abc"
echo "you entered name as " "$xyz"
```

Answer (score 1):

The issues are with your echo statements:

```
echo "Hiiii"
echo "haaaaa"
echo "Chris"
echo "Morris"
```

You are just printing the string but not storing it in variables which you can display as your expected output:

```
echo "you had put salutation as" "$abc"
echo "you entered name as " "$xyz"
```

The values stored in `abc` and `xyz` as you entered will be `1` and `1`. Use variables to store values and display them when required. Like, replace echo's with following:

`disp_sal="Hiiii"`  `disp_sal="haaaaa"`

`disp_name="Chris"` 
`disp_name="Morris"`

also,

```
echo "you had put salutation as" "$disp_sal"
echo "you entered name as " "$disp_name"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
#!/bin/sh
    echo "hello"
    echo "enter the salutation $abc"

    read -r abc

    if [ "$abc" = "1" ]
    then
        x="Hiiii"
    elif [ "$abc" = "2" ]
    then
        x="haaaaa"
    fi

    echo "enter name $xyz"

    read -r xyz

    if [ "$xyz" = "1" ]
    then
         y="Chris"
    elif [ "$xyz" = "2" ]
    then
         y="Morris"
    fi
    echo "you had put salutation as" "$x"
    echo "you entered name as " "$y"
```